# bake strange black corners and black points

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking

finally after all day trying and looking here, and youtube videos, i baked my first test object.

i managed to bake multimaterial object into a single baked texture.

but now i have this black corners and black points.

i am rendering with cycles.

[image]

[image]

of course without baking, the 3d is perfect
please. help me